# Click on button issue on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I needed to click twice button id '#a' in order the console.log('A') display on my console. But once you click already twice then succeeding click works already. I don't understand why on the first attempt need to click twice before it function well. Any Help

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalAdd" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalAdd">Add Category <small>&raquo; Category</small></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div id="container-option-add"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="a">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#addData').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('#a').off().on('click', function () { 
        console.log('A');
    });               
}).modal();
```

Comment: why're you nesting click events? any specific reason? Also read about event bubbling and event capturing in jQuery. You'll get a fair idea as to what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

**Because the first time you click the button you are only registering the event listener**, *which means you were not having listener before that so your code is not executing.*

You have to do it like this([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghd8hfpe/)):

```
$('#addData').on('click', function() {
    if($(event.target).is("#a")){
        console.log('A');
       }

});
```

Comment: also look how beautiful the `is` method is.

Answer (score 0):

When you first click the button (or at least appear to click it),

> the event handler is NOT attached to the button at this point, hence the console.log() does not fire.

The event then bubbles up to the parent `#addData` in this case, and fires the click event of that `div`.

> NOW, the event handler gets attached to the button.

Hence, the next time you click the button, the event handler starts working.

**NOTE:** the event will still continue to propagate to the parent `#addData` div.

[This](http://jsbin.com/baduzu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) should give you a fair idea

Instead of nested click handlers think of it in such a way,

```
function A(){
    $("#a").off().on("click", function(){
        //do Something
    });
}
```

Now,

The `.on('click')` for your button won't be attached until you call `A()`.

Equating it to your code,

```
$("#addData").on("click", function(){
    A();
});
```

Hope that answers your question :) 
Although, I'd highly recommend that you ***don't*** nest event handlers the way you're doing it now.

Answer (score -2):

This may work! I got the answer

```
$('#addData').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
   $(this).find('#a').off().on('click', function () { 
      console.log('A');
   });               
}).modal();
```